# Java Game Of Life doesn't follow the universe rules

Tags: java

Hello helpful developper,

As homework I need to develop the famous Game Of Life, with some code already made by the teacher, and we have to build it with the functions they gave us. Reading the universe is not a problem, but the program does not calculate the amount of neighbours correctly. Below I will post my code, and I would be very grateful if anyone could help me out! I've been staring at the code thinking about what could cause the problem, and I have tried outputting all the coordinates that the programm checks, including the amount of living neighbours. I found out that that is the problem. For example, when I try imputting the 'glider' (with text files included in the zip file we got from the teacher) the top part is not counted as alive, but the cell in the middle is. What should I change? Or where could it be wrong? Cell is an Enum in one of the other java files in the imported zip file containing {DEAD, LIVE}.
EDIT: the function updatescreen() is also in another java file

```
package nl.ru.ai.exercise6;

import nl.ru.ai.gameoflife.Cell;
import static nl.ru.ai.gameoflife.Universe.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameOfLife
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.print("What is the universe name?");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = scanner.nextLine();
        Cell[][] universe = readUniverseFile(fileName);
        Cell[][] nextGenWorld = Arrays.copyOf(universe, universe.length);
        System.out.print("How many generations do you want to evolve?");
        int totalGen = scanner.nextInt();
        int currentGen = 0;
        do
        {
            showUniverse(universe);
            nextGenWorld = nextGeneration(nextGenWorld);
            universe = Arrays.copyOf(nextGenWorld, nextGenWorld.length);
            currentGen++;
            sleep(1000);
        }
        while (currentGen <= --totalGen);
        scanner.close();
    }

/**
 * Reads the file for a universe to use in the Game of Life. Also checks the universe if it follows the rules of the game.
 * @param fileName
 * @return the universe that is read from the file, as long as it follows the rules.
 */
    static Cell[][] readUniverseFile(String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        assert (fileName != null) : " there is no file name!";
        final int maxRow = 40;
        final int maxCol = 60;
        Cell[][] universe = new Cell[maxRow][maxCol];
        try 
        {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            for (int row = 0; row < maxRow; row++) 
            {
                String universeLine = input.readLine();
                if (universeLine == null) 
                {
                    input.close();
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The universe contains less than 40 lines!");
                }
                if (universeLine.length() != maxCol) 
                {
                    input.close();
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The universe has a line which does not contain 60 characters");
                }
                if (row == 0 || row == maxRow-1)
                {
                    for (int col = 0; col < maxCol; col++) 
                    {
                       if (universeLine.charAt(col) != '.')
                       {
                            input.close();
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The universe requires a border of dead characters!");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (universeLine.charAt(0) != '.' || universeLine.charAt(maxCol-1) != '.') 
                    {
                        input.close();
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The universe 'requires a border of dead characters!");
                    }
                }
                for (int col = 0; col < maxCol; col++) 
                {
                    if (universeLine.charAt(col) == '.') 
                    {
                        universe[row][col] = Cell.DEAD;
                    }
                    else if (universeLine.charAt(col) == '*') 
                    {
                        universe[row][col] = Cell.LIVE;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        input.close();
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The universe has an invalid character");
                    }
                }
            }
            String universeLine = input.readLine();
            if (universeLine != null) 
            {
                input.close();
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The universe contains more than 40 lines!");
            }
            input.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new FileNotFoundException("The universe does not exist");
        }
        return universe;
    }

/**
 * Shows the universe on the screen.
 * @param universe
 */
    private static void showUniverse(Cell[][] universe)
    {
        assert(universe != null) : "There is no universe!";
        for (int row = 0; row < universe.length; row++) 
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < universe[row].length; col++) 
            {
                updateScreen(row, col, universe[row][col]);
            }
        }
    }

/**
 * Compiles the next generation of the universe.
 * @param universe
 * @return the next universe
 */
    private static Cell[][] nextGeneration(Cell[][] universe)
    {
        assert(universe != null) : "There is no universe!";
        final int maxRow = 40;
        final int maxCol = 60;
        Cell[][] nextGenWorld = universe;
        for (int row = 1; row < maxRow-1; row++) 
        {
           for (int col = 1; col < maxCol-1; col++)
           {
               int livingNeighbours = nrLivingNeighbours(universe, row, col);
               if (universe[row][col] == Cell.LIVE) 
               {
                   livingNeighbours--;
                   if (livingNeighbours == 2 || livingNeighbours == 3)
                   {
                       nextGenWorld[row][col] = Cell.LIVE;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       nextGenWorld[row][col] = Cell.DEAD;
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                  if (livingNeighbours == 3)
                  {
                      nextGenWorld[row][col] = Cell.LIVE;
                  }
               }
            }
        }
        return nextGenWorld;
    }

/**
 * Counts the number of living neighbours of a cell (including cell itself if alive).
 * @param universe
 * @param row
 * @param col
 * @return the number of neighbours as int.
 */
    private static int nrLivingNeighbours(Cell[][] universe, int row, int col) 
    {
        assert(row>=1 && row<39) : "Invalid row specified";
        assert(col>=1 && col<59) : "Invalid column specified";
        assert(universe != null) : "There is no universe!";
        int liveNeighbours = 0;
        for(int rowCounter = -1; rowCounter <= 1; rowCounter++)
        {
            for(int colCounter = -1; colCounter <= 1; colCounter++)
            {
                if (universe[row+rowCounter][col+colCounter] == Cell.LIVE)
                {
                    liveNeighbours++;
                }
            }
        }
        return liveNeighbours;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! As part of asking a question, it's good practice to explain what you've already tried to debug this, and the posting only the MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - this is likely why somebody downvoted your question right off the bat. In other words, if you've debugged your application and identified where the issue is, only post that function so people can help debug further without having to look through the whole application.

Comment: My first suggestion would be because you've already identified that `nrLivingNeightbours` is returning the incorrect count, add some breakpoints there and step through the function to analyze the surrounding cells to figure out where it may be going wrong.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Thanks! As I am new here, I had no clue about how to properly ask a question, and wanted to be inclusive as possible. I will try to use your tip about the breakpoints, and see what info that will give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem could be caused by:

```
universe = Arrays.copyOf(nextGenWorld, nextGenWorld.length);
```

If I remember correctly, the array returned by Arrays.copyOf with objects is the same as the array provided. This is because the array you are using is of type Cell. Because Cell is not a primitive, instead of its value being duplicated into the new array, the object is copied into the new array.

In this case, you would probably want to:

1) Define a new array of Cells that has the same dimensions as the old one.

2) Iterate through the array of cells and make a new Cell at each index (and each cell in the new array would store the same information as in the first array).

Eg:

```
Cell[][] nextGen = new Cell[universe.length][universe[0].length];
for(int r = 0; r < nextGen.length; r++)
{
   for(int c = 0; c < nextGen[0].length; c++)
   {
         nextGen[r][c] = new Cell(/*provide arguments such that this cell stores the same info as universe[r][c]*/);
   }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! The problem indeed was that the current universe and nextgeneration were not copied correctly apparently. Changing this helped! @LethalLadders